# Problem with copying JPG file content StreamReader and StreamWriter

Tags: .net, character-encoding, io

I'm having a problem where my program cannot read most of the characters on the input stream with StreamReader. It loads only first 16b of each character and if character is 32b, it trashes the remaining 16b(making all of them 0's).

I need to manipulate the content of file (encrypt & decrypt later). It works fine with ASCII, UTF-8, UTF-7.

Here is an example of the chosen image and the image after being encrypted and decrypted:
[image: Before and After]

Already tried with `Encoding.Default` or setting an encoding & nothing works.

The code I wrote IS WORKING correctly with .txt file in english only, thats not the problem. Got problem with loading the file with `StreamReader`s encryption, cause by dataloss. The chosen and the result files are with same size, it just nulls some data.

Comment: The `StreamReader` tries to first autodetect the encoding and if it can't, then it will use the user-provided encoding.  After calling your first `Read`, you can access the `CurrentEncoding` property on the `StreamReader` and see if it changed.  It would be interesting to see if that's what's happening.  Also, your title says that you're copying jpg file content, but in your question you say you're copying text files.  I'm wondering which you're doing because `StreamReader` is only intended for text files.

Comment: It's going to be hard for people on a public forum to examine the bug in your code if you won't share your code.  It doesn't have to be exact, create a sample function that exhibits the same behavior and we can look at that.

Comment: @dontangg: Can you post that as an answer, I'd like to give you a +1 (you've identified the failure point: `StreamReader` for binary data).

Comment: Already working, using BinaryReader / Writer. Ty 4 help

Answer (score 2):

For a non-text file, you should probably use a [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) and [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx).  That will allow you to read/write bytes directly and avoid having them interpreted as text (which is what the StreamReader would do).

Comment: Already working, using BinaryReader / Writer. Ty 4 help. Got +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

The `StreamReader` tries to first autodetect the encoding and if it can't, then it will use the user-provided encoding. After calling your first `Read`, you can access the `CurrentEncoding` property on the `StreamReader` and see if it changed. It would be interesting to see if that's what's happening.

Also, your title says that you're copying jpg file content, but in your question you say you're copying text files. I'm wondering which you're doing because `StreamReader` is only intended for text files. You could use a `BinaryReader`, but I think I would just use the `Stream` in this case.  `StreamReader` is designed for character input in a particular encoding, whereas the `Stream` class is designed for byte input and output.

Comment: Ty 4 help. Working now. U also got +1 from me ;)